# Passport local authentication strategy via API

Tags: node.js, vue.js, passport.js

Currently I am trying to build out an API for my web application, which includes building out the registration and login routes. Currently the register route works just fine, however, I am having trouble implementing a good way to manage the login request with a JSON response. Eventually, I am going to be using this API for my Vue application. However, I can't figure out how to do so.

Here is some code including my model and current code.

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    avatarURL: String,
    secret: String,
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    classes: [String],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

And here is my code for the routes... I need to add a JSON response and give the user a session

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/todolist',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
    })
);
```

This is all using the passport framework. I am open to other suggestions in regards to the formatting of my authentication. If there is a better way of going about this please respond.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session):

```
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (req.session.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```

You can add attributes to the session object by doing something like `req.session.newEmailAttribute = "example@gmail.com`. You would normally do this on the login or register event. You would then verify that this exists when users make requests to visit other endpoints in your application. You can verify this using conditional statements as shown in the example above.

so in passport:

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/todolist',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
    }),
    function(req, res) {
        // if this function gets called, the authentication was successful
        req.session.email = req.body.email;
    }
);
```

And then, to verify that the user is logged in:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.email) {
        // user is logged in!
    } else {
        // user is not logged in!
    }
})
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback... Do you know if it is possible to check for this session in Vue. How would I go about making sure that a user is authenticated in Vue

Comment: You could do this by creating an API at a certain endpoint and `res.send` the json to that api, and then in a vue method, use axios to get that data from the endpoint and check if the data meets the conditional requirements. I kind of have the same system in a project I built a little while back if you want to look at it to give you some perspective: https://github.com/tbragg0/GradeGoalsCalculator

Comment: actually go here: https://github.com/tbragg0/GradeGoalsCalculator/blob/master/app.js. Look at line 98.